# Как добавить подпункты в верхнем многоуровневым меню Битрикс?

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс

Как сделать чтоб в главном меню так же отображались подпункты из левого меню?

[image: нужный результат]

Короче, в разделе "компания" так же как и в разделе "каталог"(подпункты в каталоге строятся на основе инфоблоков)?
У главного меню тип - верхнее, у левого - левое, у подменю - левое подменю.

[image: проблемное место]

Comment: Подпункты в главном меню не отображаются, если: а) в параметрах компонента меню указана глубина меню "MAX_LEVEL" => "2", б) шаблон компонента меню пропускает пункты меню, у которых $arItem['DEPTH_LEVEL'] > 2.